# How to have Go To Declaration in right-click menu after left double-clicking on a statement?

Tags: pycharm, contextmenu

How can the right-click menu be configured to have the `Go To` `>` `Declaration or Usages` option the same way in both cases shown below?

Using a simple code example:

```py
def a_func():
    pass

def b_func():
    a_func()
```

**Case 1:**

If we right-click on [a statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) of a declared object in a `.py` source file the `Go To` `>` `Declaration or Usages` option is available in the menu. As show in the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of right-click menu on object]

**Case 2:**

However, if we **first** left double-click on the declaration and **second** right-click on the declaration, the `Go To` `>` `Declaration or Usages` option is not available in the menu. As shown in screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of right-click menu on object after double left-click]

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> works in both cases, but when using only the mouse I want the same option on right-click regardless if I left double-clicked before or not.

I tried searching for a way to do this, apparently the configurations are in `Settings` `>` `Menus and Toolbars` `>` `Edit Popup Menu`, but I can't understand what `EditorPopupMenu` needs to be changed and how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened for me in PyCharm (2020.3). You can add the individual `go to declaration` etc actions to the menu, but not the entire `Go To` menu itself.

This is due to a class attribute in a file in `<install path>\JetBrains\Pycharm Community Edition 2020.3\lib\resources.jar`. Inside that jar under `idea/LangActions.xml` is a group definition for `EditorPopUpMenu.GoTo`. The class attribute, `class="com.intellij.ide.actions.EditorPopupNoSelectionGroup"` is what prevents the `Go To` menu from appearing when text is selected.

It is possible to unzip the jar with a utility like 7zip, remove the `class="com.intellij.ide.actions.EditorPopupNoSelectionGroup"` attribute inside `LangActions.xml`, replace the new `resources.jar` with the old one in your install path, and the menu should appear in both contexts. This is a pretty dirty hack, but I have confirmed that it works.